# How to convert function based views to class based views in Django RestFramework?

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner learning the Django RestFramework. I had created this for an blog post page for my project. I looked through different tutorials and posts but couldn't really figure out. Can you help me converting this functional view into a class view? Thanks

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import PostSerializer
from .models import Post,categories

# Create your views here.
@api_view(['GET'])
def apiOverview(request):
    api_urls={
        'List':'/article-list/',
        'Detail View':'/article-detail/<str:pk>/',
        'Create':'/article-create/',
        'Update':'article-update/<str:pk>/',
        'Delete':'/article-delete/<str:pk>/',
    }
    return Response(api_urls)

@api_view(['GET'])
def articleList(request):
    articles=Post.objects.all()
    serializers=PostSerializer(articles,many=True)
    return Response(serializers.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def articleDetail(request,pk):
    articles=Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializers=PostSerializer(articles,many=False)
    return Response(serializers.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def articleCreate(request):
    serializers=PostSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializers.is_valid():
        serializers.save()
    return Response(serializers.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def articleUpdate(request,pk):
    articles=Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializers=PostSerializer(instance=articles,data=request.data)

    if serializers.is_valid():
        serializers.save()
    return Response(serializers.data)

@api_view(['DELETE'])
def articleDelete(request, pk):
    articles=Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    articles.delete()
    return Response('The item has been deleted')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from rest_framework import generics

class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer


class PostDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',PostList.as_view()),
    path('<int:pk>',PostDetail.as_view())
]
```